# Non-programmatic Causes for a Web Api 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api

I've been researching what can cause a 404 error on a call to a Web Api page/method, but so far every answer I'm seeing is along the lines of 'you coded the path incorrectly' or 'you coded your http mapping incorrectly'. The error is happening for one specific install for one specific client - no other client installing the program is having this problem. Therefore we know it must be a problem with their install or their setup, and *not* the code.

Does anyone know the potential *non-programmatic* causes for a 404 error? It's very difficult to try and check every single aspect of a user's set up, so having some specific places to start looking would be a great help. The entire site as a whole is not failing, merely any and all calls to a Web Api page. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps their firewall or AV is blocking the page and returning a 404. Some newer firewalls do stuff like this instead of merely blocking the connection.

Comment: We've tried turning off all firewalls and anti-virus software and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: You're going to need gather more information, such as comparing their requests and responses, checking routing data etc.